# Why does Ramakrishna say God need the help of vedas to create preserve, and destroy?

Tags: vedas, ramakrishna

> The whole body of supersensuous truths, having no beginning or end, and called by the name of the Vedas, is ever-existent. The Creator Himself is creating, preserving, and destroying the universe with the help of these truths.

According to [Ramakrishna](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_6/writings_prose_and_poems/hinduism_and_shri_ramakrishna.htm) God needs the help of vedas to do things.

Why does God need vedas to do creation, preserving, and destroying, because he is all powerful and supreme.

Comment: Veda means knowledge... Creation can not take place without knowledge.

Comment: @Tezz there is no knowledge of science(physics, chemistry, biology) in the Vedas.

Comment: How do you know it?

Comment: @Tezz by going to school, laws of physics are not mentioned in the Vedas.

Comment: maybe the school lacked competence to teach Vedas properly then... otherwise there are some persons who have derived the entire physics from Vedas itself... like here you can see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTbzgEJae0M&list=PLauldGNsA_DeumYNhKzNnOpocPwKJ5bs9

Comment: @Tezz there is no scientific verses in the Vedas. Even if there is science in the Vedas it will not be enough because vedas have less then 30,000 verse but if you look at science there are 100s of fields and 1000's of theories. The one you have give me denys big bang and has introduced his own theory called "vedic rashmi theory".

Comment: @Tezz please can you provide some verse about neutron stars or theory of special relativity or something about anti matter. Or something about quntum entanglement or quntum super position or about atoms structure or about nerves in our body. Or about speed of light. Please give verses

Comment: all the 100s of fields and 1000's of theories just have base in the four fundamental forces in modern physics.. in the same way one doesn't need a huge voluminous book.... some short suktas can itself encompass the great knowledge...

Comment: @Tezz please gave the reffence to them.

Comment: I guess, that is so that he does not do any injustice to anyone